# How can I write Snippets in Visual Studio Code with an "$" inside of them?

Tags: php, json, visual-studio-code, code-snippets

I want to make a Code-Snippet in VSC but when I make a snippet and paste the code with "$" inside of it the "$" dissapears. I know why but I dont know how I can fix this.

This is for a PHP Site I'm coding on.

```
//MYSQL - VERBINDUNG
"MySQL Verbindung": {
    "prefix": "db_verbinden",
    "body": [
        "$dburl = 'localhost';",
        "$username = 'root';",
        "$passwort = '';",
        "$dbselect = 'db';",
        "",
        "$db = mysqli_connect($dburl, $username, $passwort) or die('Die Verbindung mit der Datenbank ist fehlgeschlagen!');",
        "mysqli_select_db('rbcms', $db);",
        "",
    ]
},
```

So I want to make Snippets with "$" inside of them.

Answer (score 1):

As it is mentioned in the documentation you need to escape certain characters:

> Below is the EBNF (extended Backus-Naur form) for snippets. With `\`(backslash), you can escape `$`, `}` and `\`. Within choice elements, the backslash also escapes comma and pipe characters.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_grammar

Comment: Thanks, I'll look at the doc. the next time!